# Alternative to exceptions for methods that return objects

Tags: c++, exception

I have a class that can perform many types of transformations to a given object.

All data is supplied by the users (via hand crafted command files) but for the most part there is no way to tell if the file commands are valid until we start transforming it (if we checked everything first we'd end up doing the same amount of work as the transformations themselves)

These transformation methods are called on the object and it returns a newly transformed object however if there is a problem we throw an exception since returning an object (even a blank object) could be confused with success whereas an exception sends a clear signal there was a problem and an object can not be returned. It also means we don't need to call a "get last error" type function to find out exactly what went wrong (error code, message, statement, etc.)

However from reading numerous answers on SO it seems this is incorrect since invalid user input is not an exceptional circumstance and due to the complexity of this thing its not uncommon for the user to submit incorrect command files.

Performance is not really an issue here because if we hit an error we have to stop and go back to the user.

If I use return codes I'd have to take the output object as a parameter and then to check the return codes I'd need long nested if blocks (ie. the way you check HRESULT from COM)

How would I go about avoiding exceptions in this case while still keeping the code reasonably tidy?

Comment: Can't you add a flag in the object itself to tell if that instance is valid or not?

Comment: ¤ The main answer is to not make design changes to accommodate silly ideals. Be practical, and remember Ronald Reagan's words: if it ain't broke, don't fix it. That said, you could use the Barton Nackman "Fallible" concept, a return object type that can be logically empty, and where access of the contained value fails if it's empty. Failure can be termination or exception. The `boost::optional` class is based on exception for invalid result access. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: @puller: Thanks for the comment but I still would need to check that flag somewhere (I don't want to keep processing once that flag is set) if I'm going to check a flag I might as well check a return value.

Comment: @Cube Then I think exceptions are exactly what you need in this context :)!

Comment: @Alf P. Steinbach: Thanks for the comment, depending on the answer I may not change this class, however I still want to learn about the best way to do this because if tomorrow they let me rebuild this thing I'd build it the same way and I want to improve my thinking.

Comment: So does your current code look like "A a1 = f1(a); A a2 = f2(a1); A a3 = f3(a2);..."?

Comment: @Cube: that ain't a comment, it's the complete answer. ;-) please read it all. however, for some "ideals"-world support, see also ruben's answer. **Grumpy when people don't READ**, but cheers anyway,

Comment: @Alf P. Steinbach: Sorry, I did read it all but I assumed the reason you didn't submit as answer is because checking for a empty object type leads to same issues as checking for a return type. Felt like an answer to me as well, why not submit it as one? :)

Comment: @Cube: because the meta police here on SO insist that I do not include any salutation or good wish such as "cheers". They seem to be so retarded that they confuse that with a "signature", and so authority-oriented that last time they shut me out of chat here for a week. So in this world of retarded meta-police, I just do as they say, or in the end (most probably) leave this site to the kids.

Comment: @Cube: re "checking for a empty object type leads to same issues as checking for a return type", nope. Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The design of your problem really lends itself for exceptions. The fact that program execution will halt or be invalid once the user supplies a bad input file, is a sign of "exceptional circumstance". Sure, a lot of program runs will end in an exception being thrown (and caught), but this is in one execution of the program.

The things you are reading about exceptions being slow when used for every other circumstance, is only valid if the program can recover, and has to recover often (e.g. a compiler that fails to find a header in a search directory, and has to look at the next directory in the list of search directories, which really happens a lot).

Use exceptions. When in doubt, measure if this is killing performance. Cleaner code >> following what people say on SO. But then again, that would be a reason to ignore what I just said.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I wouldn't (avoid exceptions). If you really need an "error reporting" mechanism (and you do), there is not much besides return values and exceptions. I think the whole argument about what is exceptional enough (and therefor deserves exceptions) and what is not, is not that important to keep you from solving your problem. Especially if performace isn't an issue. But if you REALLY want avoid exceptions, you could use some kind of global queues to queue your error iformation. But that is utterly ugly, if you ask me.